# Ruby on Rails, Model Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have 2 models:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :categories, :foreign_key => "category", :class_name => "Category"
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :videos
end
```

This is fine so far, in my videos controller for the index page I have:

```
def index
@videos = Video.all(:joins => :categories)

etc, etc
end
```

The above produces the following SQL Query: SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.id = `videos`.category

Which is fine up to a certain point, basically I need to get the category name (a field in that table) that way I don't have to do another call in the view to get category name based on the category id. Any ideas?

Thank you, and yes I am new to ruby, I tried reading the API but couldn't find much help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think the association in your `Video` class is set up incorrectly. It should be:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

You can do `@videos = Video.all(:include => :category)`. This will retrieve the video and associated category records using a single SQL statement.

Incidentally, your `:class_name` option on the `belongs_to` association is redundant because ActiveRecord will already have automatically inferred the class name from the association name. You should only use this option if you want to have an association name that is different from the underlying class e.g. authors/Person.

Comment: When I do, the query changes to: SELECT * FROM `videos`

No join or nothing, that's actually how I had it before and it never worked... :(

Comment: Thanks John, the reason why I have the :class_name and renamed it to :categories, is because if I don't, when I edit I get the following error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in VideosController#update

Category(#2175068700) expected, got String(#2148246520)

The only way I found to bypass this was by doing the above....I think I have too big of a mess on my hands lol.

Comment: And btw that worked beautifully on the show & index screens, now how do I get the edit&new screens to work? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: It sounds like your associations are a bit messed up. Your `videos` table should have a `category_id` foreign key integer field if you set things up as per my answer. And it's impossible to answer your question about the edit and new screens without seeing your code! You should post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you John!!!1 I changed the field to category_id and all my problems went away. I owe you a million bucks!!! lol

Comment: I'll look forward to receiving the money in the mail!

Answer (score 0):

```
join_condition = " ,categories where INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id=videos.category"

@videos = Video.all(:joins => join_condition)
```

try this

Comment: I don't think the join statement is correct: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id=videos.category' at line 1: SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` ,categories where INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id=videos.category